# Scapy can't import Dot11

Tags: python, networking, scapy, sniffing, wifi

I can't seem to be able to import Dot11 on scapy. 
When I do `from scapy.all import *` and use Dot11 I get a NameError, because it was not imported. 
When i try to directly import Dot11 by using `from scapy.layers.dot11 import Dot11` I get:

> socket.error: can't use AF_INET6, IPv6 is disabled

The linux kernel I'm using really doesn't have support for IPv6, but I don't see any reason why Dot11 should need IPv6 to work. 
Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you retry using the latest dev version ? Download it on https://github.com/secdev/scapy/archive/master.zip , unzip it and `python setup.py install`

Comment: Tried it and I'm getting the same error